# Discord.py music bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello I'm trying to create a music bot. I run the bot on a pterodactyl gaming panel. I try to install PyNaCl and move it to the panel via filezilla. I keep getting this in my console: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to import it in the code

Comment: I did that already I'm not that stupid

Comment: Well you haven’t provided any code so it’s difficult for us to diagnose your problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ScLrMeiC

Comment: Do **not** post links, you’re supposed to add your code to your question, not in some links in the comments